# Fact Table Load Approach

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, etl, ssis

I created enclosed data model based on star schema, i have loaded all the dimensions but trying to figure out a way to load fact table.

My confusion here is with the foreign keys for e.g. I have about 6787 records from "Manufacturer" i.e ManfID table but there are about 50 K records from "Dim_Transactions" i.e Transaction ID

Not sure how this would be stored on Fact table, is this a design flaw ? How can I fix this ?

I think this can be managed by having multiple values across all keys for e.g. there will be 50K fact record with other keys repeating themselves.

If that is so how would I load the fact table, I am using SSIS here and have also created lookup files to uniquely identify Primary Key using other columns

[image]

Comment: Why are transactions a dimension and ATMs - a fact? I think it should be the other way around. Transaction is a typical business event with measurements or facts (e.g. amount) and descriptive information that should go into dimension tables (ATM is one of the pieces of this information).

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of dim_Transactions.  The embedded dimensions for branch and region exist elsewhere.  Aggregate the Approved, Declined, and Reversal CashAmt columns as measures in Fact_ATM if you need them.

Sometimes people keep a copy of the transaction table in the data warehouse or staging database for audit or reporting, but there is no reason to put it in a star schema.

In a way, and I'll get a load of grief for this, a transaction can be viewed as a fact table at the finest possible grain.  But transactions represent an atomic event and I can't think of how one could inhabit a dimension.

Comment: Those are all good points, but do not answer the question asked at all.

Comment: Hmmm, I think it answers this question:
   "...is this a design flaw ? How can I fix this ?"